# Angular HTTP POST request doesn't create anything

Tags: php, angular, http, post

I'm using Angular with PHP and trying to post an object. Request status is 200, but $_POST array is empty. Data I'm sending is a valid JSON Object.

```
sendTweet(){
    if(!this.username || !this.tweet){
      alert("Enter username or tweet");
      return;
    }
    const newTweet:Tweet = {
      username: this.username,
      tweet: this.tweet
    }
    //Call Service
    this.testService.postTweet(newTweet).subscribe((response)=>{console.log(response)},
    (err:any)=>{
      console.log(err.message);
    });

  }
```

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  })
};
```

```
postTweet(tweet:Tweet):Observable<Tweet>{
    const url = `${this.apiUrl}/?page=submit&action=add`;
    return this.http.post<Tweet>(url,tweet, httpOptions);
  }
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['tweet'])&&isset($_POST['username'])) {
            //Sending tweet to the db
        } else{
   print_r($_POST);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried logging the received object in PHP?

Comment: @Mohamed.Karkotly I've just tried it and the object shows up. So, does it mean that the object had been posted?

Comment: Check your database to determine that, see if the object actually exist there.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if its a backend problem with php but in my project i have it a little bit diferent (i am using .net core for backend)
for example in my project:

```
//service component WebScrapLinkService
get(): Observable<Any[]> {
    return this.http.get<Any[]>(this.url)
    .pipe(map(res => res));
  }
//main component
getRegisters() {
    this.getProductsSub = this.crudService.get()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.registers = data;
      })
  }
//variables
public registers: Array<object> = [];
//the service goes in the constructor
private crudService: WebScrapLinkService
```

this works fine for me, i hope it is useful for you

Answer (score 0):

It was just me not knowing that in PHP you have to parse HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA in order to get the data.